# Как выбрать всех пользователей по общей сумме, на которую они купили?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы - пользователи и их покупки:

```
users
 id
 name

statistics
 id
 sum
 user_id
```

Нужно, в общем, выбрать всех пользователей по общей сумме, на которую они купили.
Делаю запрос, почему-то не работает:

```
SELECT user.*
FROM users, (SELECT SUM(statistics.sum) FROM statistics) as sum
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Comment: А как у вас связаны эти таблицы?

Comment: statistics
 id
 sum
 user_id

Comment: @Ali, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, структура у вас неверная. Тем не менее попробуйте так:

```
SELECT u.name,
       SUM(s.sum) AS sum 
  FROM users u
  JOIN statistics s
    ON s.user_id = u.id
  GROUP BY u.name
  ORDER BY sum DESC
```

**Обновление**

Лучше делать 3 таблицы:

```
users: id | name
products: id | name | price
orders: id | user_id | product_id | quantity
```

А запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT u.name,
       SUM(p.price * o.quantity) AS sum
  FROM users u
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.user_id = u.id
  JOIN products p
    ON p.id = o.product_id
  GROUP BY u.name
  ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало)) А вообще как лучше делать структуру?

Comment: Обновил ответ.